# How to specify columns we want from eager load

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am using beyondcode/laravel-comments (https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-comments) and I try to specify columns I want to get from commentator. here is the code:

```
$comment = $post->comments()->with('commentator', function ($query) {
        $query->select('commentator.name', 'commentator.email');
        //or $query->select('users.name', 'users.email');
})->latest();
```

I am getting error that said

```
Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "commentator" // or users
```

How can I fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns), just do your eager load like this to specify columns, no function needed:

```php
$comment = $post
    ->comments()
    ->with('commentator:id,name,email')
    ->latest();
```

If you do need to use a callback to alter the eager load, you would have to use an array as shown [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```php
$comment = $post
    ->comments()
    ->with([
        'commentator' => fn ($q) => $q->select('id', 'name', 'email')
    ])
    ->latest();
```

Comment: Do note, you should always run the `id` when eager loading specific columns, `('commentator:id,name,email')`.

Comment: these codes are returning 502 bad gateway without any log from server. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @Cutis that seems unlikely; 502 is typically a problem with PHP-FPM.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I had a problem with the package https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-comments
I will mark your answer accepted, because it helps me for my own laravel relationships. Thank so much @miken32

Answer (score -1):

```
$comment = $post->comments()->with('commentator:primary_key,your_column_name')->latest();
```

When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.